# Multi-objective optimization problem

Tags: optimization, convex-optimization, matlab, nonlinear-optimization

I would really appreciate it if anyone can help me with my question.

I'm dealing with a multi-objective optimization problem which I simplified here with just two variables to get some insight. Let's consider that we have two functions $f_1(x_1,x_2)=\frac{ax_1}{bx_2+c}$ and $f_2(x_1,x_2)=\frac{dx_2}{ex_1+f}$. The goal is to maximize $f_1(x_1,x_2)$  and $f_2(x_1,x_2)$ over $0\leq x_1\leq 1$ and $0\leq x_2\leq 1$. By deriving the Hessian matrix I know that $f_1$ and $f_2$ are jointly concave with respect to $x_1$ and $x_2$. I am looking for a proper tools for solving this problem in matlab. Can anyone guide me?

Thank you in advance!

Comment: What does it mean to maximize the two functions?  They needn't attain their maxima at the same point.

Comment: @saulspatz In my problem, these two functions need to be maximized concurrently. The optimum value for maximizing $f_2$ over $x_2$ is $x_2=1$. But on the other hand, by choosing  $x_2=1$ we are reducing the $f_1$. I think a tradeoff is needed here to reach the goal

Comment: Yes, that's what I'm saying.  We can try to maximize $f_1(x)+f_2(x)$ or  some other function of $f_1$ and $f_2$, but in general, trying to maximize both concurrently won't work.

Comment: @saulspatz I see. Let's say the goal is to maximize the sum of these two functions, now, what is a proper tool for solving such a problem?

Comment: Now you just have a real-valued function of two variables, and the standard techniques can be applied.

Comment: @saulspatz Do you think defining a slack variable q and maximizing it,  in which $q\leq f_i $, is a good idea?

Comment: I don't see how that will help at all.  It's just a standard calculus problem if you want to maximize the sum.

Comment: @saulspatz Thanks for your help!